# Как отсортировать ArrayList<String> по убыванию вставленных целочисленных чисел типа String

Tags: java, строки, коллекции, arraylist, substring

Столкнулся с задачей отсортировать биржи по объему, от большего к меньшему, но, все перевести я должен в ArrayList, если с названием и URL проблем нет, то вот как отсортировать по убыванию думаю весь день.

Методом .sort() не получается, к сожалению.

Объект в ArrayList выглядит так:

```
4710,BitMart-https://www.bitmart.com/trade/en?layout=basic&symbol=XCAD_USDT| $XCAD / $USDT |
```

4710 - объем

Как по нему отсортировать?

Comment: `Методом .sort() не получается` что не получается?

Comment: вообще задача выглядит как "спарсить число из строки и по нему отсортировать"

Comment: `Collections.sort(list, (d1, d2) -> d2.volume - d1.volume);`

Comment: Что такое _числовые числа типа String_?

Comment: Не правильно выразился, целочисленные числа типа String 
Не 7, а "7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "числовое число" находится в начале строки и после него следует запятая, можно вырезать подстроку до первой запятой при помощи `String::substring` + `String::indexOf`, преобразовать её в целое при помощи `Integer::parseInt`, и отсортировать при помощи `Comparator.comparingInt` + `Comparator::reversed`

```java
list.sort(
    Comparator.<String>comparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(
        s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","))
    ))
    .reversed()
);
```

Comment: Да, это то что было мне нужно, храни тебя вселенная)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял как у тебя хранятся данные в `ArrayList<String>`
То думаю можно сделать так:

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("2");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("5");
        
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        Вывод [2, 1, 6, 5]
        list.sort(new Comparator<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
        
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        Вывод [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

**UPD**

```
list.add("2,  F");
list.add("1, C");
list.add("6, A");
list.add("5, D");
Вывод [2,  F, 1, C, 6, A, 5, D]

        list.sort(new Comparator<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2)
            {
                o1 = o1.substring(0, o1.indexOf(","));
                o2 = o2.substring(0, o2.indexOf(","));
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
Вывод [1, C, 2,  F, 5, D, 6, A]
```

Comment: Нет, данные хранятся в виде - {4710,BitMart-https://www.bitmart.com/trade/en?layout=basic&symbol=XCAD_USDT| $XCAD / $USDT |}

Comment: @Ewrey тогда как то так получается, изменил ответ